# Does Wowza Streaming Cloud use origin server bandwidth for each connection?

Tags: video-streaming, cdn, broadcast, bandwidth, wowza

i have been using multiple servers with wowza because one server is not enough to handle my viewers as servers are limited to 1Gbps Upload Bandwidth.

I have recently tried wowza streaming cloud, when i stream a video and i have like 100 viewers i notice that my server`s bandwidth is not really been used for all 100 viewers its just uploading one video.

Is it really true that for each connection/viewer Wowza Streaming Cloud will not use my servers bandwidth like CDN Does?

Like i am streaming at 1mbps, and i have 100 viewers, my server is supposed to upload at 100mbps, but how does it work with Streaming Cloud? will it only upload 1mbps from my origin server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew,

When using the Wowza Streaming Cloud, the streaming engine is pushing one copy of your video feed to the CDN even if there are no users viewing that feed. The streaming cloud CDN caches this one copy and sends it on to end users when they request it. Basically your origin server bandwidth becomes fixed and your variable bandwidth based on viewer count all happens at the CDN.